# Django Application Assign Stylesheet -- don't want to add it to app's index file? Can it be dynamic?

Tags: python, django

I am new to Django framework and kindly consider if my question is novice.

I have created a polls application using the django framwork. I am unable to figure out how to make my stylesheet dynamic for front end. As i dont want to call it in my base_site.html or index.html files as I am also multiple views render different template files. My only aim is to how i define my app's stylesheet on one place and applicable through out my application.

Comment: Don't put "wanna" in your question if you wanna be taken seriously.

Comment: The problem with making your stylesheets dynamic is that you then have to server them from your application server as opposed to allowing your proxy or web server manage them - this will heavily increase the load as you are then generating the css as well as html on each request. @dm03514's suggestion of including them in your html is a good one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i'm reading your question correctly the first part wants to make a stylesheet that is dynamic???

> I am unable to figure out how to make my stylesheet dynamic for front
>   end

For that you could use something like

Django admin follows convention of adding `{% block extra_head %}` (or something similar, sorry don't remember specifics)

Which is exactly what it sounds like a block that is in the `<head>` tag.  This will let you load a stylesheet from any template.  Just define that block in your `base_site.html` and implement it when you extend `base_site.html`

But then at the end of your question you it seems you want to define style sheet in one place and include that stylesheet for every request?

> My only aim is to how i define my app's stylesheet on one place and
>   applicable through out my application.

Perhaps you could set up a directive in your settings.py `'DEFAULT_STYLESHEET` and include that in your `base_site.html` template.  Put the css in the block extra_head.  If you need to override it just implement that block and viola!

Comment: The extra_head block is nice. You can also split your styles into a basic CSS file, and other CSS files according to the page you're displaying. If some CSS code is dynamic, you could generate it on the fly, or better, write a dynamic CSS file and use it afterwards.